# How to pass String url into URL of kotlin?

Tags: http, kotlin, httprequest

The statement

```
val address = URL("http://192.168.43.22:5000/post_message")
```

Throws the error

```
Expression 'URL' of type 'String' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found
```

I cannot figure out why this happens. I have searched internet for an hour and came up with nothing.

Comment: URL has a String constructor, so where's the code the error points to? Because if that's the line, this isn't possible to reproduce

Comment: If URL has a string constructor then it should work fine but it does not. The error only points to the above mentioned line. Thank you for looking into it. @Zoe

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not using the required imports.

Try using

```
import java.net.URL
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a `const val URL = "..."` somewhere which it is prioritizing over the class `URL`. So your code is actually calling the invoke operator on a string.

You can rename the import `import java.net.URL as JURL` and then use `JURL` to work around that. Alternatively you can try to find out exactly what is defining `URL` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

```
var url = URLEncoder.encode("https://your.url/");
```